# Forcing Gradle to use an earlier dependency version for testing

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

Is there a way to construct a Gradle build file to force the test phase to use an earlier version of a dependency than the one used for compilation and and packaging?

I'm attempting to [set up an HBase mini-cluster via HBaseTestingUtility](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_integration_testing_with_a_hbase_mini_cluster) to test my project; unfortunately, HBaseTestingUtility relies on an old version of Guava (14.0.1 seems to work), while the rest of my project uses 18.0. Here are excerpts of my build script, as-is (I'm also using the [Gradle test-sets plugin by unbroken-dome](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin) to create two separate sets of tests):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets' version '1.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

ext.verGuava = '18.0'
ext.verGuavaTEST = '14.0.1'

testSets {
    testUnit { dirName = 'test/unit' }
    testIntegration { dirName = 'test/integration' }
}

configurations {
    provided
    provided {
        extendsFrom(compile)
    }
    testIntConf
    testIntConf {
        extendsFrom(provided)
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.google.guava:guava:${verGuavaTEST}"
            forcedModules = ["com.google.guava:guava:${verGuavaTEST}"]
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    testUnit.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    testUnit.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
    testIntegration.compileClasspath += configurations.testIntConf
    testIntegration.runtimeClasspath += configurations.testIntConf
}

dependencies {
    provided "org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:${verHBase}"
    provided "org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:${verHBase}"
    compile "org.testng:testng:${verTestNG}"
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hadoop', name:'hadoop-common', version:"${verHadoop}", classifier: 'tests'
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hbase', name:'hbase-server', version:"${verHBase}"
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hbase', name:'hbase-server', version:"${verHBase}", classifier: 'tests'
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hbase', name:'hbase-hadoop-compat', version:"${verHBase}"
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hbase', name:'hbase-hadoop-compat', version:"${verHBase}", classifier: 'tests'
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hbase', name:'hbase-hadoop2-compat', version:"${verHBase}"
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hbase', name:'hbase-hadoop2-compat', version:"${verHBase}", classifier: 'tests'
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hadoop', name:'hadoop-hdfs', version:"${verHadoop}"
    testIntegrationCompile group:'org.apache.hadoop', name:'hadoop-hdfs', version:"${verHadoop}", classifier: 'tests'
}

testUnit {
    useTestNG()
    logger.info "@@@ Classpath (UNIT testing): ${classpath.getFiles().collect({it.toString()}).inject('\n') {acc, next -> acc + next + '\n'}}"
    logger.info "@@@ SystemProps (UNIT testing): ${System.getProperties().collect({it.toString()}).inject('\n') {acc, next -> acc + next + '\n'}}"
}

testIntegration {
    useTestNG()
    systemProperty "java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true"
    logger.info "@@@ Classpath (INTEGRATION testing): ${classpath.getFiles().collect({it.toString()}).inject('\n') {acc, next -> acc + next + '\n'}}"
    logger.info "@@@ SysProps (INTEGRATION testing): ${System.getProperties().collect({it.toString()}).inject('\n') {acc, next -> acc + next + '\n'}}"
}
```

When I run a build via this script, I get the following output which seems to show that Guava 14.0.1 was *added* to the classpath for the testIntegration target, rather than *replacing* Guava 18.0:

```
@@@ Classpath (UNIT testing):
/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/cce0823396aa693798f8882e64213b1772032b09/guava-18.0.jar
@@@ Classpath (INTEGRATION testing):
/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/cce0823396aa693798f8882e64213b1772032b09/guava-18.0.jar
/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1/69e12f4c6aeac392555f1ea86fab82b5e5e31ad4/guava-14.0.1.jar
```

This behavior is probably to be expected; the API indicates that [`ResolutionStrategy.force(...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force%28java.lang.Object[]%29) **appends** artifacts to the list to be considered.

How can I direct Gradle to eliminate Guava 18.0 from the classpath for the testIntegration target entirely?

I have tried changing the `sourceSets` section to assign the classpaths using **=** rather than **+=**:

```
sourceSets {
    ...
    testIntegration.compileClasspath = configurations.testIntConf
    testIntegration.runtimeClasspath = configurations.testIntConf
}
```

This has the desired effect as far as eliminating Guava 18.0 (and retaining 14.0.1), but it seems to prevent Gradle from detecting the location of the `testIntegration` source files, for some reason, so the `testIntegration` tests are never compiled or executed.

I have also tried a few variations on purging Guava from the inherited configuration, such as the following:

```
configurations {
    provided
    provided {
        extendsFrom(compile)
    }
    testIntConf
    testIntConf {
        extendsFrom(provided.copy {
            exclude group:"com.google.guava", module:"guava"
        })
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.google.guava:guava:${verGuavaTEST}"
            forcedModules = ["com.google.guava:guava:${verGuavaTEST}"]
        }
    }
}
```

The above (and all other variations I've tried) do successfully eliminate the duplication of the Guava artifact in the classpath, but they seem to nullify the `resolutionStrategy`, as the resolved artifact is always the newer version (18.0) even in `testIntegration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While perhaps not the most elegant solution (and I'd still be interested in a cleaner one, if it exists), an approach which seems to work is to create a completely separate configuration which contains the newer Guava dependency **only**, then use [`FileCollection#minus`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#minus%28org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection%29) to subtract that configuration from the classpath within the testIntegration target itself.

Firstly, create the configuration; I call it `guava` here since its sole purpose is to contain the Guava 18.0 artifact that I want to exclude from the `testIntegration` classpath:

```
configurations {
    guava
    ...
}
```

(The configuration should contain the Guava artifacts in isolation, so it should **not** `extendsFrom` any other config.)

Secondly, add the artifact to be excluded from the classpath to the dependency list for the newly-created configuration. In this case, I know that the main configurations resolve com.google.guava:guava to version 18.0, so I add a dependency on that version of Guava to the `guava` configuration:

```
dependencies {
    guava group:'com.google.guava', name:'guava', version:"${verGuava}"
    ...
}
```

Thirdly, invoke [`FileCollection#minus`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#minus%28org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection%29) on `classpath` in the Gradle target wherein you want to force the earlier version of the dependency, in order to exclude the newer dependency. My `testIntegration` block above is tranformed thusly:

```
testIntegration {
    classpath = classpath.minus(configurations.guava);
    ...
}
```

So, the quick summary of how this works in the Gradle build is:

1. Create a configuration which `extendsFrom` the main configuration (e.g. `compile`), then use [`ResolutionStrategy#force`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force%28java.lang.Object[]%29) and [`ResolutionStrategy#forcedModules`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:forcedModules) to **add** the earlier version of the dependency to that configuration's dependency list.
2. Create a *second* configuration which does not extend from anything, intended to hold the **newer** version of the dependency.
3. In `sourceSets`, append the configuration created in Step 1 to the `compileClasspath` and `runtimeClasspath` for the target where you wish to force the earlier dependency version.
4. In `dependencies`, add the newer version of the artifact as a dependency for the configuration created in Step 2.
5. The `classpath` in the target block now contains the union of the default dependencies **plus** the earlier version, as a result of the actions taken in Steps 1 and 3. To remove the *newer* version, set `classpath` to [`classpath.minus(newerDependencyConfiguration)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#minus%28org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection%29), where `newerDependencyConfiguration` is the one created in Step 2.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem but simpler version. cause I am not differentiate the integration test and unit test.  using this seems give the right guava dependency for test

```
   configurations {
        all{
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4'
            }
        }
        testCompile{
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
dependencies {
 testCompile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-testing-util', version: '1.2.4'
}
```